# use xsl to change the name of an element which is placed right after another specific element

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

I have an XML file of this sort:

```
<section>
  <section>
    <title>this is title 1</title>
    <p> first paragraph after the title for which I need to change the element name </p>
    <p>second paragraph</p>
    <p>second paragraph</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <p>paragraph</p>
    <title>this is title 1</title>
    <p> first paragraph after the title for which I need to change the element name </p>
    <p>second paragraph</p>
    <p>second paragraph</p>
  </section>
</section>
```

What I need is to figure out an XSL transformation that will change the element name of each `<p>` element right after the title element (first p element after title element).

The idea is that after the transform the output xml should look something like the following:

```
<section>
  <section>
    <title>this is title 1</title>
    <p_title> first paragraph after the title for which I need to change the element name </p_title>
    <p>second paragraph</p>
    <p>second paragraph</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <p>paragraph</p>
    <title>this is title 1</title>
    <p_title> first paragraph after the title for which I need to change the element name </p_title>
    <p>second paragraph</p>
    <p>second paragraph</p>
  </section>
</section>
```

I can't find a template select expression that will allow me to select such elements since it is not allowing me to use the siblings axis.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean about it not allowing the sibling axis, because the following should work

```
<xsl:template match="p[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::title]]">
```

i.e. Match the **p** element whose first preceding-sibling is a **title** element.

Or, if it could be any element, not just **p**, this should work:

```
<xsl:template match="*[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::title]]">
```

Try the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="*[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::title]]">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}_title">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you been about "it is not allowing me to use the siblings axis" but the following works:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <!-- The identity transform. -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Match p elements where the first preceding sibling is a title element. -->
  <xsl:template match="p[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::title]]">
    <p_title>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </p_title>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```